# Can Android Studio create a MySQL database in fact of a table?

Tags: android, database

I'm creating an App on Android Studio and I need a long database. If a user register in the app, i want in that action to create a new database with a random id (assigned to that user) in fact of a new table, I want a full database. Is it possible with Android Studio? I didn't find nothing... Sorry for my English :(

Comment: Android does not have much to do with MySQL. MySQL is something that would run on a server. Do you mean SQLite?

Comment: Google Room will help you to create a local database and save data in it.  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In android you can store data locally using sqlite you can follow this link

[Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)

keep coding :)